# How to verify if a delegate responds to a selector?

Tags: iphone, delegates, selector

I know I need to write:

```
 [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod:)]
```

But the compiler is complaining that respondsToSelector is not a method in the protocol, which is correct, However I have seen many sample code use this, how do you do it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your `@protocol` needs to implement `<NSObject>`, simply update your protocol definition to look like this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but when i add the <NSObject> the compiler complains that no type may be specified before interface

Comment: I got it working i was trying to implement <NSObject> in the protocol declaration not in the formal definition, it is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

[Greg Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239194/how-to-verify-if-a-delegate-responds-to-a-selector/2239210#2239210) has your answer, but here is a quick explanation of *why* the compiler complains:

The `respondsToSelector:` method is part of the `NSObject` protocol, so when you try to send that message to your deleate (of type `id`), the compiler has no way of knowing that your delegate might be able to handle it.